# How to apply ApexChart in Angular 11,12,13?

Tags: angular, charts

**ng-ApexCharts** is an ***Angular*** wrapper component for ApexCharts ready to be integrated into your Angular application to create stunning Charts. In this post, you will learn how to use **ng-ApexCharts** to create various charts in your web application with ease.

[Do reffer given Image as a final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hNw4.png)

1. Install using npm

```
npm install apexcharts ng-apexcharts --save
```

2. Open angular.json and under scripts add

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.min.js"
]
```

3. Add ng-apexcharts-module to imports

```
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  NgApexchartsModule,
  ...
]
```

4. Once you have installed the library, you are ready to create a basic bar chart in Angular. So, let’s get started. We start with the app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";

import {
  ChartComponent,
  ApexAxisChartSeries,
  ApexChart,
  ApexXAxis,
  ApexTitleSubtitle
} from "ng-apexcharts";

export type ChartOptions = {
  series: ApexAxisChartSeries;
  chart: ApexChart;
  xaxis: ApexXAxis;
  title: ApexTitleSubtitle;
};

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild("chart") chart: ChartComponent;
  public chartOptions: Partial<ChartOptions>;

  constructor() {
    this.chartOptions = {
      series: [
        {
          name: "My-series",
          data: [10, 41, 35, 51, 49, 62, 69, 91, 148]
        }
      ],
      chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: "bar"
      },
      title: {
        text: "My First Angular Chart"
      },
      xaxis: {
        categories: ["Jan", "Feb",  "Mar",  "Apr",  "May",  "Jun",  "Jul",  "Aug", "Sep"]
      }
    };
  }
}
```

5. And, in app.component.html, put this

```
 <div style="text-align:center">
  <apx-chart
    [series]="chartOptions.series"
    [chart]="chartOptions.chart"
    [xaxis]="chartOptions.xaxis"
    [title]="chartOptions.title"
  ></apx-chart>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After compiling above code you will get below **errors** :-

```
Error: src/app/apex-chart/apex-chart.component.html:3:8 - error TS2322: Type 'ApexAxisChartSeries | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ApexAxisChartSeries | ApexNonAxisChartSeries'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ApexAxisChartSeries | ApexNonAxisChartSeries'.

3       [series]="chartOptions.series"
         ~~~~~~

  src/app/apex-chart/apex-chart.component.ts:20:16
    20   templateUrl: './apex-chart.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component ApexChartComponent.


Error: src/app/apex-chart/apex-chart.component.html:4:8 - error TS2322: Type 'ApexChart | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ApexChart'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ApexChart'.

4       [chart]="chartOptions.chart"
         ~~~~~

  src/app/apex-chart/apex-chart.component.ts:20:16
    20   templateUrl: './apex-chart.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component ApexChartComponent.


Error: src/app/apex-chart/apex-chart.component.html:5:8 - error TS2322: Type 'ApexXAxis | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ApexXAxis'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ApexXAxis'.

5       [xaxis]="chartOptions.xaxis"
         ~~~~~

  src/app/apex-chart/apex-chart.component.ts:20:16
    20   templateUrl: './apex-chart.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component ApexChartComponent.


Error: src/app/apex-chart/apex-chart.component.html:6:8 - error TS2322: Type 'ApexTitleSubtitle | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ApexTitleSubtitle'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ApexTitleSubtitle'.

6       [title]="chartOptions.title"
         ~~~~~

  src/app/apex-chart/apex-chart.component.ts:20:16
    20   templateUrl: './apex-chart.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component ApexChartComponent.
```

**Solution**:- *Add the exclamation mark ***(!)*** to the properties like below*.

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <apx-chart
      [series]="chartOptions.series!"
      [chart]="chartOptions.chart!"
      [xaxis]="chartOptions.xaxis!"
      [title]="chartOptions.title!"
    ></apx-chart>
  </div>
```